# angular's element.isolateScope() returns undefined

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, chai

I'm writing a test for [this directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27393759/angular-directive-does-not-update-as-scope-updates), and I believe I'm doing it correctly, but when I try to access the isolateScope, I get undefined.

Directive:

```
describe('directive: deposit-note', function() {
  var expect = chai.expect;

  var element,
      scope,
      $rootScope,
      $compile,
      $httpBackend;

  beforeEach(module('directives.depositnote'));

  beforeEach(inject(function (_$compile_, _$rootScope_) {
      $compile = _$compile_;
      $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
  }));

  beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
  }));

  describe('with a filled-out transaction object', function() {

    beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
      $httpBackend.whenGET('/templates/depositnote.tpl.html').respond(200, '');
      scope = $rootScope.$new();

      element = '<deposit-note checknumber="transaction.checkNumber" checktype="transaction.checkType.value" depositnote="transaction.depositNote" />';

      scope.transaction = {
        "checkNumber": "1234",
        "checkType": "CASHIERS CHK",
        "depositNote": "In Person"
      };

      element = $compile(element)(scope);
      scope.$digest();
    }));

    it("should calculate the correct remaining characters", function() {
      var isolated = element.isolateScope();
      expect(isolated.totalRemaining).toBe(17);
    });  
  });
});
```

When I step through this, I see element get compiled, and chrome's devtools shows that `element.isolateScope()` is indeed a method on element, but it returns undefined.

What am I missing?

Comment: The function name in the title is mis-spelled: isolatedScope() should be isolateScope(). Just a warning for copy-pasters such such as myself :-) > (just fixed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My karma.config file had the incorrect base url to access the template in the template cache (I use html2js). So essentially the template was not available, so the directive was never compiling, which is why an isolate scope was never being created.